# how to remove duplicate rows on the basis of single column in Spark SQL using JAVA

Tags: java, apache-spark-sql

I need to understand How can I remove duplicate rows from a Data-frame on the basis of single in Spark SQL using Java.

Like in normal SQL, ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY col 
ORDER   BY Col DESC). How Can I translate this step into Spark SQL in Java?

Answer (score 1):

You can remove duplicates from dataframe using dataframe.dropDuplicates("col1"). It will remove all rows which has duplicates in col1. This API is available from Spark 2.x on wards.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking correctly. We should use the windowing function and then filter out dataframe with row_number=1 to get the lastest record(order by field helps in giving row_number).

Follow the below links.

http://xinhstechblog.blogspot.com/2016/04/spark-window-functions-for-dataframes.html

[How to use Analytic/Window Functions in Spark Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33319279/how-to-use-analytic-window-functions-in-spark-java)